# cloudfoundry groovy (java) app fails to read external url giving 403

Tags: http, url, groovy, cloud-foundry

https://groups.google.com/group/caelyf/feed/rss_v2_0_topics.xml in a browser window correctly returns xml stream;

Using groovy in cloudfoundry app, this fails with http 403 permission failure like:

```
def url = "https://groups.google.com/group/caelyf/feed/rss_v2_0_topics.xml:443".toURL()
def tx = url.getText('UTF-8')
```

cloudfoundry forum implies only https plus port 443 can read an external url

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

not sure why you stuck `:443` on the end of the url?

403 means forbidden. I'm guessing Google doesn't let you scrape the groups site with java.

you could try setting the user agent to that of a browser?

```
def tx = url.openConnection().with {
  setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Firefox/2.0.0.4")
  inputStream.with {
    def ret = getText( 'UTF-8' )
    close()
    ret
  }
}
```

or similar...

I don't think this is a cloudfoundry issue.  have you tried running the above from your machine to confirm this?

### Edit:

Just tried it, and it works (at least on my machine).  This shows how to load the XMl into a parser, and print the titles from the feed:

```
URL url = "https://groups.google.com/group/caelyf/feed/rss_v2_0_topics.xml".toURL()

def tx = new XmlSlurper().with { x ->
  url.openConnection().with {
    // Pretend to be an old Firefox version
    setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Firefox/2.0.0.4")
    // Get a reader
    inputStream.withReader( 'UTF-8' ) {
      // and parse it with the XmlSlurper
      parse( it )
    }
  }
}

// Print all the titles
tx.channel.item.title.each { println it }
```

Comment: thank you very much @tim_yates for this example. its always super to see some code samples from other developers. i've never used streaming xml so this was a real eye-opener for me 8-}